# Odoo email template unable to edit and save

Tags: email, templates, save, edit, odoo-10

Dears

I am using odoo 10. I have created automated actions and used email templates in it. Everything was quiet simple and working good initially. But now I want to edit the email template and add few details in it. But when I save the template it does not show the error and what ever text/data I add to the content gets vanished. This weird behaviour happening only on the online server. On my local machine it is working fine still I can edit and save the email templates. I have tried many solutions from stack and forums but no success. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the database, if you can check that the table of content is full or not